# Injective restriction of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

Is it possible to have an entire function $f$ which is not a polynomial, and a disk $D_\epsilon(0)$ (for some $\epsilon$) such that the restriction of $f$ to $D_\epsilon(0)$ is injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Every* entire function $f$ such that $f'(0)\neq0$ has that property, for some $\varepsilon\neq0$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this fact, or is this something obvious?

Comment: @Theo It follows from the [inverse function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414044/inverse-function-theorem-in-complex-analysis)

Comment: I see, thank you. Is the converse true, that is, if some restriction is injective, then then the derivative is not zero?

Comment: @Theo Yes, the converse holds.